# Get rid of numbers from a string in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to get names from a website in a list.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
tbl = soup.find('ul', class_='static-top-names part1')
for link in tbl:
    names = link.get_text()

print(names)
```

So i'm trying to get some names from a website and when i applied above code, i get names as a . When i try to iterate over it i get below output.

1. John
2. Mark
3. Steve and so on.

I want to get rid of the number in the text data and also just want to have the names in a list format.

All i want is to get these pure names and hopefully put them in a list form. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always `#. name`, then you can do the following:

`name.split('. ', 1)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split with '.' dot character or even a space if there is a space before name.

So `name.split('' )[-1]` `name.split('.')[-1]` would give just the name. Then you can append those names into a list.

Something like this.

`names = [link.get_text().split(' ')[-1] for link in tbl]`

This will you the list of just names, i used `[-1]` as the list index after since your text contains only two items after splitting with space. So if there are more items please use appropriate index.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression for consistency.

```
import re

s = '1.TEST'

print(re.sub('\d+.','',s))
```

will give you TEST only. This will eliminate any size of number following with a dot. Basically, replace any number followed by a dot with emptiness.

Iterate over your original list and do the above at the same time using list comprehension

```
new_list = [re.sub('\d+.','',s) for s in original_list]
```

This should give you the new list as per your requirement.